# Programmatically adding Segue to UIImageView Which forwards it to a new ViewController Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a SrollView In which already 3 views added(view1,view2,view3).I want to add an Image on the view3 programmatically.
When you click on the image it will go to a new view controller which is a different one (DestiationViewController).
And After that, I want to enable NSUserDefault for one time clicking action so that if the image is clicked once it will go to DestinationViewController.During 2nd time run, It will directly go to DestinationViewController.

Please help me really difficult one for me since am a beginner.

Advance Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your UIImageView click event add following code to open your destination view controller :

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:"SegueIdentifier" sender:self];
```

To set UIImageview clickevent use following method :

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *newTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(myTapMethod)];

[myImageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

[myImageView addGestureRecognizer:newTap];




 -(void)myTapMethod{
        // treat image tap

       NSString *valueToSave = @"destinationVisited";
      [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:valueToSave 
forKey:@"preferenceName"];
      [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

      // Navigate
      [self performSegueWithIdentifier:"SegueIdentifier" sender:self];
    }
```

Add you can set NSUserdefault and when click on image update NSUserdefault value and check NSUserdefault at app delegate and open your destination view controller as per NSUserdefault  value.

Check NSUserdefault at viewWillAppear or app deleget method as per your requirement.

```
NSString *savedValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
    stringForKey:@"preferenceName"];

if(savedValue == @'destinationVisited')
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:"SegueIdentifier" sender:self];
}
```

Comment: After doing as per your advice I am getting this error -- "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not perform segue with identifier 'destination'. A segue must either have a perform handle or it must override -perform."    Please note that my StoryBoardSegue identifier name is "destination". Please forgive me if this is a minor error because am just a beginner.

Comment: Check your segue identifier, error looks like segue is not properly set.

Comment: Yes It was already solved, Anyway Thanks again for your constant resolution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it two ways.

1. In AppDelegate check the NSUserDefaults Value. If value true, then change the initial view controller Programatically. You can google for it.
   "How to change initial view controller programatically in iOS " lik this.
2. This way is not good one, but can satisfies your scenario. In Initial view controller ViewDidLoad method check the userDefaults value. If true then present Destination view Controller. But here you have to present destination controller with little time gap.

   [self performSelector:@selector(presentDestination) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];

use this method In presentDestination method you can present your destination screen.

Comment: Thank You for your quick response.Please help me if required in future.